# Viewing shapefile's attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table

How can I view the attribute table of a shapefile or a raster file as a database using ArcPy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "view" and "as a database".

To simply extract the data from a table into a data structure in Python using Arcpy, use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`.

See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

If this answer is too vague, that's probably because you're question is a little on the vague side, and it's difficult to know what it is you really want.

Eg:

```
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        print "{}, {}, {}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

Comment: I want to view the database as we do in pandas

Comment: In that case, you may want to google something like:  arcpy feature class to pandas dataframe .   This would reveal many useful answers, including:  https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/introduction-to-the-spatial-dataframe/